# Is there a way to draw a intersecting line at the line art?

Tags: modifiers

[image]

Like the red in the picture above, it worked well in the alpha version.
I'd like to have a line at the point where the faces intersect.

[image]
I want it like this.

[image]

Comment: Hello, can you show your settings ?

Comment: I solve this problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

It's because the line art is behind the mesh.
viewport display - in front